# JQuery Loop Through Elements and Return False If All Are Empty

Tags: jquery, html, loops

How do I loop through all elements of a certain class name and return false only if every element has no value/is null?

**I know that I could increment an int, or add to a string, or do something like that to test if every field is empty after the loop finishes but that seems very unsustainable, not to mention a terrible way to do it.**

Currently I have for my JS file:

```js
function verifyPositions() {
  $(".position").each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {

    }
  });
}
```

And for my HTML:

```html
<div class="spacing">
  <a class="applicationLabel">Position(s) interested in:</a><br>
  <input class="position" name="position[]" value="Project Manager" type="checkbox" /> Project Manager<br>
  <input class="position" name="position[]" value="Content Developer" type="checkbox" /> Content Developer<br>
  <input class="position" name="position[]" value="Graphic Designer" type="checkbox" /> Graphic Designer<br>
  <input class="position" name="position[]" value="Digital Media Creator & Storyteller" type="checkbox" /> Digital Media Creator & Storyteller<br>
  <input class="position" name="position[]" value="Programmer" type="checkbox" /> Programmer<br>
  <input class="position" name="position[]" value="Server Engineer/Technician" type="checkbox" /> Server Engineer/Technician<br>
  <input class="position" name="position[]" value="User Experience Designer" type="checkbox" /> User Experience Designer<br>
</div>
```

**EDIT: FIXED IT**

```
function verifyPositions() {
var flag = false;

$(".position").each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        flag = true;
    }
});

if (!flag) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: As soon as you see one in the loop that isn't null, return true. If you reach the end, return false.

Comment: Hahaha! Thanks! Clearly I wasn't thinking logically.

Comment: @JacobMattison You should post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it:

```
function verifyPositions() {
var flag = false;

$(".position").each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        flag = true;
    }
});

if (!flag) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function verifyPositions() {
    $(".position").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() !== "") {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: whoops, the comment beat me  :P

Comment: That would halt as soon as it finds one checked checkbox, though.

Comment: is that what he wants?  only return false if all are empty?

Comment: I can guaranty that it will always return false no matter if there are any checked or not.

Comment: Your `return true` is only going to return from the `.each()` not from  `verifyPositions()`

Answer (score 0):

I misread the question and was thinking about it differently. If you only want to return false if NONE of the checkboxes are checked, then you could use this:

`return $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length != 0;`

I'm leaving the below for posterity, in case you want to ensure that ALL the checkboxes are checked.

The following will tell you whether or not all the checkboxes are checked:

`return $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == $('input[type=checkbox]').length;`

If you're only concerned about all the checkboxes in a specific area being checked (such as your `<div class='spacing'>`, you could then use:

`return $('div.spacing input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == $('div.spacing input[type=checkbox]').length;`